# Populate Null Records with Last Non-Null in List

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to develop a script that will iterate through a list of values within a FBGDB table/field and insert the last non-null value that was found into the ones that are null.

Here's what the table looks like:
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy

updatecursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("D:\Tools\Scripts\insert over null\Testing.gdb\Test_tbl", ["From_Value", "To_Value"])

for row in updatecursor:
    if row[0] is None:
        print "There are Nulls"
        row [1] = row[0]([-1])
        print row[1]
    else:
        row[1] = row[0]
        print "Has Value"
    updatecursor.updateRow(row)
del row, updatecursor
```

I know my issue is in `row[1] = row[0]([-1])` but I can't figure out how to make it read backwards to the last non-null value which in theory would be the previous value in the list (assuming it's populating as it iterates through.

Comment: From the help: 'Cursors can only be navigated in a forward direction; they do not support backing up and retrieving rows that have already been retrieved. If a script needs to make multiple passes over the data, the cursor's reset method may be called.'  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/data-access-using-cursors.htm

Comment: Thanks GISKid.  Yeah from everything I read, it looks like I'd need to use PANDAS (http://pandas.pydata.org/) in order to read backwards.  Unfortunately I'm on an air gapped secure network, and wouldn't be able to install it.

Comment: Could you install R? Or QGIS ?

Comment: I could probably install QGIS.

Comment: Special thanks to FelixIP, aldo_tapia, HDunn, mgri, Evil Genius who marked this question as a duplicate.  I referenced the other thread and although it was a solution using Python with ArcGIS Desktop Field Calculator, I was able to get things going.  I took the easy route and dumped the Field Calculator Tool into a GP Model, filled in the codeblock accordingly.  Exported the model to a Python script, and done.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, I agree with the comment posted above, there is no way to go back through a cursor.  That said, you could always just save the last non null value as a local variable and apply that.  So, it may be something like

```
updatecursor = ... :
    lastNonNullValue = None
    for row in updatecursor:
        if row[0] is not None:
            lastNonNullValue = row[0]
        else:
            row[0] = lastNonNullValue
            updatecursor.updateRow(row)
```

Be warned this is only pseudo~ish code; I've not double checked all of the syntax and you may have to adjust for your needs as I wasn't perfectly clear with your existing code which field you were trying to populate with which values since you have the same values in both fields in the example, but hopefully that helps give you some ideas of how to proceed.  FYI also, I'd recommend looking up using `with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(...) as updatecursor:` instead of creating and deleting it separately, as that way even if there is an error you know the cursor gets closed for sure (see the samples at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

Comment: Thanks John.  Sorry for the bad screen shot of the table.  I had already run some tests which populated the second field (To_Value) with the values from the first field (From_Value).  As you can see it just duplicated the values.  I tried your idea of saving the last non-null value as a variable and populating the nulls with that value, but didn't have much luck.